# Basic question on application of Sunflower lemma

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

A *sunflower* or $\Delta$-*system* is [a collection of sets $\mathscr{F}$ whose pairwise intersections are all the same set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_%28mathematics%29) $S$, possibly empty.  Elements of the collection of sets $\mathscr{F}$ are called "petals".

[Sunflower lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_%28mathematics%29#Sunflower_lemma_and_conjecture) states that:

> Let $F$ be a family of sets each of cardinality $s$. 
>   If $|F| > s! (k-1)^s$, then $F$ contains a sunflower with (at least) $k$ petals.

This is an area I am not familiar with and this might be a bit silly question. 
But I was just wondering, can I apply
this result when $F$ is a family of sets of polynomials over a finite field?
(Does it matter it is non-zero characteristic by any chance?)

Comment: Yes. (And it does not matter.)

Answer (score 0):

The Sunflower lemma doesn't use any field structure, or any other structure, for that matter.  It's only about sets, subsets, intersections, etc.  So, yes, you can apply it without worry.